# How to parse the JSONP(JSON with Padding) response?

Tags: android, jsonp

i am getting lot of confusion in doing this. what i have to do is, parse the JSONP response coming from server and display it. Is it possible to parse JSONP response in Android?

Here is my response looks like:

```
{
    "Reference1":"String content",
    "Reference2":"String content",
    "Reference3":"String content",
    "Reference4":"String content"

}
```

Thank you

Comment: That is JSON, not JSONP.

Comment: @Quentin, but it is showing This operation supports JSONP responses. The callback function can be specified using the "callback" Url query parameter. in the help page..

Comment: — Since you aren't writing JS that runs in a browser, you don't need JSONP, so the ability of the service to optionally provide it isn't relevant.

Comment: @Quentin, when i parse this using JSON parser, i am getting null response.. How it occurs?

Comment: Are you trying to convert these strings into `JSONObjects` and get the values out? Have you tried `jsonObj.getString(tag_name)`?

Comment: @Quentin.. i tried like this..
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
   JSONObject json_object = null;
   
   for (String url : urls) { 
    json_object = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url);    
    if(json_object == null) 
     break;
   }
   return json_object; 
  }

Comment: @wolverine — I haven't a clue. I've never used any of those functions.

Comment: @Quentin it is just as you  said, you are using jsonobject.getString("tag"); instead of this i am using the above one, if there is some thing in the JSONOBJECT, it should not be null... so i used that one.

Comment: @wolverine — I am not Jermin Bazazian

Comment: @JerminBazazian  i tried like this.. protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) { JSONObject json_object = null; for (String url : urls) {  json_object = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url);  if(json_object == null) break; } return json_object;  }, you are using jsonobject.getString("tag"); instead of this i am using the above one, if there is some thing in the JSONOBJECT, it should not be null... so i used that one.

Comment: @Quentin.. Sorry, i just realized and mentioned that name..

Comment: I am gonna answer your question below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have been doing in many projects is to first convert the string read from http stream to JSONObject using the code below:

```
JSONObject jsonOBJ=new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Then use `jsonobject.getString("tag")` to read each tag. For your code it'd be something like:

```
String reference1=jsonobject.getString("Reference1");
```

Now the value of referece1= `String content`

And here is my http get code:

```
String url="Your URL Goes Here";
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response;
try {
    try 
    {
      InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName(url);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
        stringContent=new StringContent(result);
        instream.close();
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And below is the `convertStreamToString` block

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) 
{
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
     */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: is it possible to pass special characters in url?

Comment: when i am sending url in the restclient, it is responding, and the response is in json format, but when i go through the eclipse program it is showing null value..

Comment: Added the http get and stuff let me know if you still have any problem

Answer (score 0):

The padding itself is never an issue. Every decent JSON parsing library will handle it transperantly. I personally adivse you to use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. I have used it in many projects, and never found a thing to complain about.

PS: Maybe I misunderstand you, but when you say parse, I assume you need to get the values for the attributes and do not need to preserve any padding, right?

Answer (score 0):

i think this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) is very detail of parsing json in android.Hope this help you.

Comment: Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”? ([No, they aren't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers))